# Prevent an Android service to be killed

Tags: android, .net-core, android-widget, avalonia

Currently I have an Android foreground service as backend and another app as frontend.

Backend will comunicate with the hardware and frontend app is for users to sontrol the hardware, and backend and frontend are different (Their application IDs are not the same).

Now I have problem is the backend will be recycled sometimes. I don't think something crashes it because it has no error in log files.

I already made backend as a foreground service and it had a notification, but this way just reduced the chance of death. Redeliver Intent and Sticky are not working either.

I also tried to create another service (Same application ID with backend) to watch the status of backend but it didn't work.

Now I'm considering two methods to deal with this issue.

1. Use frontend app to watch the status of backend
2. Create a visible and transparent widget to wathc the status of backend (Same application ID with backend)

1 is my wrost choice because I don't want another app to handle this issue. But I believe this should work.

I have no idea it's possible or not at 2. But I think if the widget is visible, then OS won't kill it.

The way at 2 will have a timer to check the status of backend, and if it's death, just send an intent to recover it.

Is the way of 2 possible?

Thanks!

--- Update ---

Our device will be running in kiosk mode. So basically it will always make screen on.

The device would be the orignal Android OS (version 9 or later). And it's not the normal phone like Pixel, Samsung...etc. It's provided by our own manufacturer.

Comment: Failing to understand what is stopping you from trying the 2nd option? If it works, just go with it.

Comment: What device(s) have you experienced this on?

Comment: "I already made backend as a foreground service and it had a notification, but this way just reduced the chance of death. Redeliver Intent and Sticky are not working either." -- this is [expected behavior](https://dontkillmyapp.com/). "I'm considering two methods to deal with this issue" -- neither of those will help with the screen off or with another app in the foreground. If your target hardware is Samsung, you could register for very infrequent GPS locations -- in my testing, that helps a fair bit.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realize it is imposible.

I also tried to use WindoManager and add a custom view, but the value of oom_score_adj is still 200.

Seems has no way to prevent OS to kill the process in the background.